# Session is expired when working on two different projects at same time

Tags: session, sugarcrm

I have two projects of `sugarcrm` installed on my local server, nothing wrong with that.

Now I start my first project i.e. `sugarcrm` in the browser, login with the credentials, and after that when I opened the second project i.e. `demo_sugarcrm` in the browser and login, my `sugarcrm` session is expired.

And same with the `demo_sugarcrm` also. Its session expired when I login to the `sugarcrm`

What is going on here, I have totally different database of both. they dont share anything except that both are on local sever.

Answer (score 2):

I think adjusting unique_key is supposed to fix this, but as an alternative you could modify /etc/hosts such that 'sugarcrm' and 'demo_sugarcrm' hostnames both reference 127.0.0.1. Then you could visit `http://sugarcrm` and `http://demo_sugarcrm`. I'm sure any shared cookie mayhem would go away at that point since the browser would consider these to be distinct sites.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you edit config.php and change the unique_key variable to be different between the two instances then you shouldn't get kicked out anymore.

Comment: I found that the unique_key value is some sort of encrypted in config.php and is different in both the files. How can I change the encrypted value.

Comment: It's not encrypted, just a random str.